# Java 8 convert String of ints to List<Integer>

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream, collectors

I have a String:

```
String ints = "1, 2, 3";
```

I would like to convert it to a list of ints:

```
List<Integer> intList
```

I am able to convert it to a list of strings this way:

```
List<String> list = Stream.of("1, 2, 3").collect(Collectors.toList());
```

But not to list of ints.

Any ideas?

Comment: Your last line of code will give you a list with exactly one string it, with the value `"1, 2, 3"`. Did you mean: `Stream.of("1", "2", "3")`?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You need to split the string and make a Stream out of each parts. The method [`splitAsStream(input)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#splitAsStream-java.lang.CharSequence-) does exactly that:

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(", ");
List<Integer> list = pattern.splitAsStream(ints)
                            .map(Integer::valueOf)
                            .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

It returns a `Stream<String>` of the part of the input string, that you can later map to an `Integer` and collect into a list.

Note that you may want to store the pattern in a constant, and reuse it each time it is needed.

Comment: @Igor There is no winner really, just different solutions to do the task. Creating an array and passing it to Stream.of works as well, and depending on the strings you want to parse, and the exact delimiter (if it isn't `", "`), maybe this solution with `splitAsStream` will be faster than the other. This needs to be measured.

Comment: I'd prefer this one over mine. Wasn't aware of the `Pattern.splitAsStream()` method. Excellent!

Comment: You can use `Pattern.compile(", ", Pattern.LITERAL);` to hint to the engine that there is no real pattern matching. Of course, the engine will find out itself without the flag, but specifying the flag skips the process of analyzing the pattern.

Answer (score 24):

Regular expression splitting is what you're looking for

```
Stream.of(ints.split(", "))
      .map(Integer::parseInt)
      .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: Yes, but he specifically asked for Java8 way to solve this

Comment: This won´t create a List<Integer>

Comment: I always recommend to use `Arrays.stream` if the input is an array, i.e. when there is not a real varargs invocation. This makes it clear that we stream over an array and will work correctly for arrays of primitive types instead of creating a single element stream. For this specific case, both will do the same.

Comment: @Holger: Yeah, that's not a bad idea, although some APIs that used to take array arguments now take varargs arguments since Java 5, so, this distinction might not be eternal...

Comment: There was a retrofitting when varargs were introduced with Java 5, but that’s not something to happen again very often. And, making `Arrays.asList` a varargs method has been considered a design mistake, as it contradicts the purpose of creating a wrapper around an *existing* array (e.g. the array can be modified through the returned `List`). Java 9 is going to fix that. There, you can use `List.of(…)` to create an immutable list of arbitrary size (true varargs semantics) and `Arrays.asList(array)` to wrap an array in a mutable `List` (still being varargs due to compatibility constraints).

Answer (score 3):

First, split the string into individual numbers, then convert those (still string) to actual integers, and finally collect them in a list. You can do all of this by chaining stream operations.

```
String ints = "1, 2, 3";
List<Integer> intList = Stream
        .of(ints.split(", "))
        .map(Integer::valueOf)
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
System.out.println(intList);  // [1, 2, 3]
```

Answer (score 2):

You can just use the Array function asList, and then convert it the java8 way.

Don't forget to remove the white spaces.

```
 List<Integer> erg = Arrays.asList(ints.replace(" ", "").split(",")).stream().map(Integer::parseInt).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

EDIT:
Sorry i didn't see that it was a single string, thought it was a array of String.